# Difference between BackgroundWorker and System.Threading.Thread

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

What is the difference between creating a thead using BackgroundWorker and creating a thread using System.Threading.Thread?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class basically abstracts the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) creation and monitoring process, and gives you an event-driven API to report the progress of the operation ([ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)) and determine when your operation is finished ([RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx))...

One of the most common uses for it is to keep a Windows GUI responsive while a long-running process executes in the background. So basically, its just a wrapper for System.Threading.Thread designed to make background threading a little simpler (as the name implies!)

Comment: So basically, its just a wrapper for System.Threading.Thread designed to make threading a little simpler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread/1507337#1507337

Comment: @MattDavis Great link, it would probably be more meaningful if there was a description or something more than JUST the link.

Comment: I am trying to reconcile your comment: "while a long-running process executes in the background" with Hans Passant's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17009983/848344) where he said: "It is important that you use a thread pool [BackgroundWorker] thread only when the work it does is limited, ideally not taking more than half a second.". What gives?

Answer (score 19):

`BackgroundWorker` is actually a wrapper for asynchronous thread invocation via delegates - using reflector one can see it calls the begin/end invoke methods accordingly. This differs from a `System.Threading.Thread` in that it uses the threadpool as opposed to starting up a brand new thread.

The main reason for using background worker is that it plugs in nicely with windows forms applications.

Comment: +1 for accurately capturing the fact that background workers use the thread pool. In addition it is useful for people ot know that the BackgroundWorker is not a good choice if you need to call an STA Com object as the apartment cannot be set