# C# Polling a TCP Server

Tags: c#, tcp, polling

Hey everyone - I am wondering if anyone could help me out - I need to poll a TCP server frequently with a request to receive some real-time data.

I know I will need to create a thread in order to talk to the server but I am unsure as to how to make this poll frequently.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a background thread. Rather have a look at a Timer in System.Threading. This is exactly what it was made for. Very easy to use.

Comment: If this is used in a GUI based application, you either have to create a new thread for network connections and do the work there (to avoid blocking the whole gui) or use async network calls.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a Backgroundworker or a background Thread ([What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread)) with an endless loop, in which you sleep for a certain time (e.g. 1 minute) and poll the data.