# threading and Winforms form redrawing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I just wrote a simple app to learn multi-threading, and I'm missing something. I start a new thread that performs a relatively lengthy database operation (checking SharePoint permissions on users for a particular site), often up to fifteen seconds. This is how I am creating the thread (removing some extraneous code for simplicity):

```
private void btnSelectSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strSiteURL = txtSiteURL.Text;

    tmrProgressTimer.Interval = 1000;
    tmrProgressTimer.Enabled = true;

    ThreadStart starter = delegate { LoadUsers(strSiteURL); };
    Thread t = new Thread(starter);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();

    cboUsers.Items.Clear();
    cboUsers.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());

    tmrProgressTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

I am using a delegate to fire off LoadUsers in its own thread, since LoadUsers requires a string. It populates a generic list ("list" in the code) and I later use that to populate a combobox. My understanding is that while this thread is processing, my UI shouldn't lock up, being as it is on its own thread; however, that has not been the case. None of the UI refreshes until after the thread finishes, and the app is locked up during the thread processing -- the timer never even fires, although it should be ticking every second and the database operation is taking up to fifteen. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yuriy answered, your UI is blocked, waiting for the thread `t` to finish its work thanks to the call to :

```
t.Join();
```

<strike>**Note**: the edited solution provided by Yuriy does not work either, since the combo gets updated from the worker thread, not the UI, as Ego discovered (cross-thread accesses are not allowed).</strike>

However, if you don't do that, your code won't work either, since you seem to be expecting that the `list` was already populated by the worker thread. This most certainly won't be the case.

In order to get back the results to your combo box, you'll have (in pre-C# 5 days, at least) to do some additional processing when your `LoadUsers` method returns. Here is a suggestion of how you could implement it:

```
private void ...
{
    strSiteURL = ...

    System.Action after =
        delegate
        {
            cboUsers.Items.Clear();
            cboUsers.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
        };

    ThreadStart starter =
        delegate
        {
            LoadUsers(strSiteURL);
            this.Invoke(after);
        };

    Thread t = new Thread(starter);
    t.Start();
}
```

When your thread returns from `LoadUsers` you'll have to update the combo box. But you cannot do so in a worker thread: it must be done on the original UI thread. To do so, you'll have to call the `Invoke` method provided by your `Form` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to learn more about invoking), passing it a delegate. The `after` delegate will be run on the UI thread and all will be well.

I'd also add some code to disable the button, so that the user does not start more than one thread. And when the thread invokes `after`, you could finish by reenabling the button.

And beware of exceptions :-)

Comment: Thanks! I had to play around with it a bit (again, I'm just starting with multi-threading) but it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is

```
 t.Join();
```

You are blocking the calling thread until `t` finishes.

You can use:

```
private void btnSelectSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strSiteURL = txtSiteURL.Text;

    tmrProgressTimer.Interval = 1000;
    tmrProgressTimer.Enabled = true;

    ThreadStart starter = () => 
    {
        LoadUsers(strSiteURL);

        cboUsers.Invoke(() => 
        {
            cboUsers.Items.Clear();
            cboUsers.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());

            tmrProgressTimer.Enabled = false;
        });  
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(starter);
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error on attempting clear the combobox (cboUsers.Items.Clear();): 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cboUsers' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: @Geo sorry about that, I'll fix it in a sec.

Comment: @Yuriy: my answer contains the fix with the missing `Invoke()`.

Comment: @Yuriy: both are roughly equivalent; it's just a matter of taste. I tried to be a little more concise, so that things are clearer for someone who is not familiar with lambdas.

Comment: @Pierre -1 on that. Lambda expressions seem like the direction C# is heading. Seems like the delegate syntax is there mostly for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I did find Pierre's solution easier to follow, as I have heard of lambdas but was not familiar with them whatsoever, so it really threw me. However, seeing one in use (and seeing them more and more in general) has prompted me to finally learn their usage, so thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

I'm simply restating what others have already said.  By calling `Join()` on the secondary thread, you're effectively neutralizing the benefit of the secondary thread by forcing the UI thread to wait until the secondary thread is finished.  As you've noted, you want the two threads to run simultaneousy, with the secondary thread notifying the UI thread of the results when it finishes.

There is nothing wrong with using a formal `Thread` object to do this, but it's heavyweight.  For background tasks from a UI, I would strongly recommend using the [`System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.  This class provides a well-defined interface that allows you to periodically update the UI while the background thread is running.

For general rules-of-thumb regarding the various threading alternatives in .NET, you can refer to [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread/1507337#1507337).

Comment: Your analysis of when to use what type of threading is great. Thanks.