# When to use BackgroundWorker or Manage threads on your own?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BackgroundWorker vs background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread)

When should I consider managing threads on my own as opposed to using the BackgroundWorker?

I know managing threads on your own can be difficult and can lead to problems, is there a direct benefit of managing them on your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find an answer to this question at:

[BackgroundWorker vs background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread)