# backgroundworker c#

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use a backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker)

Please point me in to good description of how to use backgroundworker or what I must to use to keep gui from freezing while app does some long process?

Gui freezes when I do pinging process or whatever.. it's just annoying, I would like to display results of pinging different hosts while it pings it, but it's frozen untill it stops pinging all hosts in a list.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx?ppud=4

Comment: You might benefit from showing how you are using it when it freezes. I've never had that problem.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx

Comment: [When to use BackgroundWorker or Manage threads on your own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195733/when-to-use-backgroundworker-or-manage-threads-on-your-own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?ppud=4):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SL_BackgroundWorker_CS
{
    public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }
        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
        private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                bw.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
            {
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
                }
            }
        }
        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                this.tbProgress.Text = "Canceled!";
            }

            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                this.tbProgress.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }

            else
            {
                this.tbProgress.Text = "Done!";
            }
        }
        private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.tbProgress.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();//Calls worker_DoWork on a separate thread.
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)//Runs when worker_DoWork is completed.
{
    //
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```