# Limit number of downloads on MVC Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC method that returns a **FileResult**, and **I want to limit the number of concurrents downloads to max 3 downloads at same time**.

Is there a way to achieve that?

I didn't try anything because I have no idea.

Comment: You’re looking for throttling. Basic implementation will use SemaphoreSlim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849247/throttling-asynchronous-tasks-in-asp-net-with-a-limit-on-n-successful-tasks

Comment: this link don't help, I have N clients that will download the file