# How to run a lot of Tasks in batches of smaller size?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a lot of operations what i want to run async. I do:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
  tasks.Add(CreateGeoreferencedImageAsync(properties, scaleIndex, currentXmin, currentYmin, currentXmax, currentYmax));
}

while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
   var bunch = tasks.Take(4).ToList();
   bool[] firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAll(bunch);
   tasks.RemoveRange(0,4);
}
```

But i see that `WhenAll` execute all Task from `tasks` not only from `bunch`.
What i missed?

*UPDATE*

```
private Task<bool> CreateGeoreferencedImageAsync(ImageGenerationProperties 
properties, int scaleIndex,
        double currentXmin, double currentYmin, double currentXmax, double currentYmax)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return CreateGeoreferencedImage(properties, scaleIndex, currentXmin, currentYmin, currentXmax,
                    currentYmax);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Your list contains tasks that are already started. There is absolutely no reason to wait for a couple of them at a time.

Comment: So maybe the correct answer was that he should not create the Tasks with `Task.Run` but `new Task`. Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075029/have-a-set-of-tasks-with-only-x-running-at-a-time

Comment: Why don't you simply `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`? Whar are you trying to avoid?

Comment: I added method code. And i want to run just a part of Task couse i have not enough memory to run them all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)

Comment: @JoePhillips - no that is _not_ a (good) duplicate. This question is not about I/O, and that is crucial.

Comment: Just use Microsoft's Dataflow api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library

Comment: @KliverMax - you are not very clear about what you want with the returned booleans. Just disregard them?

Comment: @bommelding I got errors when used `void` and do not remove bool return value.

Comment: So, there is no return?  Are the GeoreferencedImages retrieved from one place and stored in another?  Could any of that I/O be made async?

Comment: I think that i understand idea that i gonna create new Tasks just after previous banch finish to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WhenAll` doesn't execute the tasks. It waits for them to finish. The execution usually starts as soon as the task is created, in your case inside `CreateGeoreferencedImageAsync`.

Comment: It is mean that i gonna create new banch of Tasks after previous banch finish to work?

Answer (score 3):

Forget about Tasks and especially about Task.Run().

This problem is best solved with `Parallel.ForEach()`. Or Linq's `AsParallel()`.

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, 
  new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
  i => CreateGeoreferencedImage(properties, scaleIndex, 
      currentXmin, currentYmin, currentXmax,  currentYmax));
```

Comment: I believe this is an older way to do it. Semaphores would be the newer way. I could be wrong, too

Comment: Semaphores are way older than the Parallel class. About half a century.

Comment: SemaphoreSlim isn't though. http://blog.briandrupieski.com/throttling-asynchronous-methods-in-csharp

Comment: Now is your chance to explain why to use TPL instead of the other options then. I think I understand why but I wouldn't expect others to

Comment: No, the question isn't finished yet.

Comment: I agree this is the answer but I feel its important to explain why. My understanding is that it is a cpu bound (non async) "task" that is occurring. If it were actually async then semaphoreslim would make more sense here

Comment: @JoePhillips - it's probably not really CPU bound but as long as the interface of the core method is not awaitable, Tasks and WhenAll are a clumsy workaround. And I still don't see the use for semaphores here. With or without Tasks.

Comment: @bommelding The main reason to use SemaphoreSlim here would be that Parallel.For will block threads. SemaphoreSlim can be used asynchronously. Maybe you can do the same with Parallel.For as well?

Comment: @JoePhillips - Yes, the Parallel.For() is blocking as a whole. When that is a problem, wrap it in a single Task.Run(). But there is nothing in the question that indicates that this is desired.