# Limiting concurrent async tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, semaphore

I want to upload potentially large batches (possibly 100s) of files to FTP, using the `SSH.NET` library and the [`Renci.SshNet.Async`](https://github.com/JohnTheGr8/Renci.SshNet.Async) extensions.  I need to limit the number of concurrent uploads to five, or whatever number I discover the FTP can handle.

This is my code before any limiting:

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(sftpHost, 22, sftpUser, sftpPass))
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    try
    {
        sftp.Connect();

        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(localPath, "*.xml"))
        {
            tasks.Add(
                sftp.UploadAsync(
                    File.OpenRead(file),      // Stream input
                    Path.GetFileName(file),   // string path
                    true));                   // bool canOverride
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        sftp.Disconnect();
    }
    // trimmed catch
}
```

I've read about `SemaphoreSlim`, but I don't fully understand how it works and how it is used with TAP.  This is, based on the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.7.2), how I would implement it.

I'm unsure if using `Task.Run` is the correct way to go about this, as it's I/O bound, and from what I know, `Task.Run` is for CPU-bound work and `async`/`await` for I/O-bound work.  I also don't understand how these tasks enter (is that the correct terminology) the semaphore, as all they do is call `.Release()` on it.

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(sftpHost, 22, sftpUser, sftpPass))
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
    try
    {
        sftp.Connect();

        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(localPath, "*.xml"))
        {
            tasks.Add(
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    sftp.UploadAsync(
                        File.OpenRead(file),      // Stream input
                        Path.GetFileName(file),   // string path
                        true));                   // bool canOverride
                    semaphore.Release();
                });
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        sftp.Disconnect();
    }
    // trimmed catch
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into ThreadPools? Specifically [ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_ThreadPool_SetMaxThreads_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: @DotNetPadawan As is mentioned in the question, this is not CPU bound work.  It won't be using the thread pool for the actual long running operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a set of Tasks with only X running at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075029/have-a-set-of-tasks-with-only-x-running-at-a-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from what I know, Task.Run is for CPU-bound work

Correct.

> and async/await for I/O-bound work.

No.  `await` is a tool for adding continuations to an asynchronous operation.  *It doesn't care about the nature of what that asynchronous operation is*.  It simply makes it easier to compose asynchronous operations *of any kind* together.

If you want to compose several asyncrhonous operations together you do that by making an `async` method, using the various asynchronous operations, `await`ing them when you need their results (or for them to be completed) and then use the `Task` form that method as its own new asynchronous operation.

In your case your new asynchronous operation simply needs to be awaiting the semaphore, uploading your file, then releasing the semaphore.

```
async Task UploadFile()
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await sftp.UploadAsync(
            File.OpenRead(file),
            Path.GetFileName(file),
            true));   
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call that method for each file.

Additionally, because this is *such* a common operation to do, you may find it worth it to [create a new class to handle this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691829/1159478) so that you can simply make a queue, and add items to the queue, and have it handle the throttling internally, rather than replicating that mechanic everywhere you use it.