# Run multiple asynchronous Tasks continuously

Tags: c#, async-await

I would like to implement a pool of a predetermined number (let's say 10) asynchronous tasks running undefinitely.

Using **Task.WhenAll**, I can easily start 10 tasks, feed them into a list, and call *await Task.WhenAll(list)* on this list. Once the method comes back, I can start again the whole process on the next 10 elements. The problem I face with this solution is that it waits for the longest task to complete before looping, which is not optimal.

What I would like is that anytime a task is completed, a new one is started. A timeout would be great as well, to prevent a task from being run undefinitely in case of a failure.

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered `WhenAny` instead of `WhenAll`?

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have a set of Tasks with only X running at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075029/have-a-set-of-tasks-with-only-x-running-at-a-time)

Comment: Is this a job for [`TPL DataFlow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library?redirectedfrom=MSDN) perhaps?

Comment: @ColinM yes you are right, but can I add an element to the list being awaited?

Comment: @devNull This is the exact same question, but answers are quite old, I was wondering if there was any updated way of doing it. Most of them do not use the async/await syntax.Thanks for the link anyway

Comment: @MatthewWatson I didn't know this library, it looks really promising!

Comment: The answers are quite old, but the only thing that's really changed with TPL since that time is the addition of `async`/`await`.

Comment: @XavierAM It has quite a steep learning curve, but it's the best library for "processing pipeline" style problems, IMO.

Comment: @ColinM point taken, actually one of the answer matches the TPL recommandation from Matthew.

Comment: For throttling I/O operations you can look here: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I would like is that anytime a task is completed, a new one is started.

This is a perfect use case for `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

public async Task AddTask(Func<Task> work)
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try { await work(); }
  finally { _mutex.Release(); }
}
```

> A timeout would be great as well, to prevent a task from being run undefinitely in case of a failure.

The standard pattern for timeouts is to use a `CancellationTokenSource` as the timer and pass a `CancellationToken` into the work that needs to support cancellation:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

public async Task AddTask(Func<CancellationToken, Task> work)
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  try { await work(cts.Token); }
  finally { _mutex.Release(); }
}
```