# What is the best way to create several background worker threads?

Tags: c#, threadpool

I want to perform several tasks (Disk IO on Remote Shares) at the same time.  I do not want to block the UI.  I think I need to create a custom class that does the following...

- Accepts and queues a request (using a Stack)
- Checks the thread pool and if a thread is available starts it with the requested info
- As each thread completes check the stack for pending requests...

Is there a better way to do this?

Is there a class already available for this?

Should I use a pool of the BackgroundWorker class or something else?

Will I have to implement the BackgroundWorker class in a custom class so that I can create multiple threads?

I want to create up to 8 threads for deleting files and folders.  I need to query the number of items on the stack for updating the UI.

I currently have the code working with a single BackgroundWorker thread to delete the files and folders (which keeps the UI from locking, but it takes so long I tend to run several of the utilities at the same time).

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: I know it's tagged, but does a [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) meet your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, then the Task Parallel Library looks like exactly what you need. Reference on MSDN is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx .

Specifically, the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx suggests replacing

```
foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
{
    Process(item);
}
```

with

```
Parallel.ForEach(sourceCollection, item => Process(item));
```

Just be wary of deadlocks in your code; in paricular, test extensively, as there can be strange things that happen sometimes in the depths of the Windows networking stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pool of BackgroundWorker, but note it is designed for use in simple multi-threaded scenarios.
I would recommend using TPL or Threadpool for your kind of problem, but if your code is already working with one BackgroundWorker you will be much faster, rewriting it for 8 instead of using TPL.

Maybe this discussion will help your decision: [BackgroundWorker vs. BackgroundThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread)