# Execute few methods in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I have 3 methods and I want to execute them in parallel. Unfortunatelly, I cannot use Task Parallel Library, because I work on NET 3.5 Framework.
How to use parallelism in Net 3.5? I don't want to install any extra open source libraries etc.

Comment: Search for threading…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what kind of processing your methods need to do and if they update GUI elements, you can use the following classes:

- [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)
- [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker)
- [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread) will help you figure out which is the ideal for your scenario.

Comment: I just need mathematical computation. Each computation takes ~50 ms on my cpu, so I want to do 4 computations at once. What should I use? ThreadPool?

Comment: Updated the answer, the answers in that question should help you figure out which method would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread( Method1 ).Start();
new Thread( Method2 ).Start();
new Thread( Method3 ).Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

your methods must be Static to use multi threading
first import following

```
using System.Threading;
```

then follow the following structure

```
Thread t1,t2,t3;
public static void method1()
{
   //do some thing here
}

public static void method2()
{
   //do some thing here
}

public static void method3()
{
   //do some thing here
}

public void StartworkinParallel()
{
     //initialize all threads here
    t1=new Thread(new ThreadStart(method1));
    t2=new Thread(new ThreadStart(method2));
    t3=new Thread(new ThreadStart(method3));

    // start them to simulate parallelism

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    t3.Start();
}
```

feel free to ask if any thing went wrong!