# GUI pauses until task is completed - should I use backgroundworker or is there a better solution?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

in one of my program functions, the function runs a couple of update queries on the database - this takes about a couple hundred milliseconds, but it's enough to cause a perceptible delay in the program. Should I use backgroundworker to run the update queries, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you need to update the UI after the operation?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, a `Thread` is another option for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506838/backgroundworker-vs-background-thread

Comment: @ByteBlast - No, I don't need to update the UI after the operation.

Comment: You are asking "how to keep the UI responsive while performing some work". This is very basic and has been discussed often. Hope the duplicate helps you. If not, do a web search. If that does not help either, reopen.

Comment: @user3600400 In which case, use a `Thread` or `Task` in a fire-and-forget manner.

Comment: This article should show you [when to use thread or backgroundworker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/628237/Thread-vs-BackgroundWorker)